# DobleClick para Editar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy haciendo una tabla HTML lo cual tiene los campos de: Nº, Nombre, Área, Puesto y Email, lo único que me falta es editar las filas que ya fueron ingresados en la tabla, para editarlas quiero hacer dobleclick en la fila, pero el problema es que me edita las cabeceras y no las filas.Les muestro mi código y por favor ayúdenme, estoy desesperado:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bt_add').click(function() {
    agregar();
  });
  $('#bt_del').click(function() {
    eliminar();//eliminar(id_fila_selected); podemos omitir el parámetro pues abajo lo declaras como variable global
  });

  $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
    eliminarTodasFilas();

  });


});
var cont = 0;
var id_fila_selected = [];

function agregar() {
  cont++;
  var fila =

    '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';


  $('#tabla').append(fila);
  reordenar();
}

/*
 * Esta función agrega lo ingresado a la tabla
 */
function addToTable(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
    const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
    const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
      if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
      else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
    });
  }
}

function seleccionar(id_fila) {
  if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
    $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
    // borrar también el id del array de filas seleccionadas
    var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila); 
    id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
  } else {
    $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
    // agregar id sólo si se hizo click
    id_fila_selected.push(id_fila); 
  }
  //2702id_fila_selected=id_fila;
}

function eliminar() {
  /*$('#'+id_fila).remove();
  reordenar();*/
  for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
    $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
  }
  reordenar();
}

function reordenar() {
  var num = 1;
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
    num++;
  });
}

function eliminarTodasFilas() {
  $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}

$(function () {
  
 $("td").dblclick(function () {
  var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
  $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
  $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
  $(this).children().first().focus();
  $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) { 
    var newContent = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().text(newContent);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    }
   }); 
  $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
   $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
   $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
   }); 
  });
 });
```

```css
  #content {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected:hover {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}

.seleccionada {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="content">
  <label> Tabla de Ejemplo </label>
  <br>
  <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
  <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
  <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar todo</button>

  <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nº</td>
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>AREA</td>
        <td>PUESTO</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Es decir que tienes tu tabla y cuando le dees doble click en cualquier campo de la tabla te abra y puedas editar ese campo?

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores Es correcto, es lo que quiero que haga, Mi tabla crea una fila, en ella le ingreso los datos (Nº, Nombre, Área, Puesto y Email) y los inserta en la tabla, pero solo me falta editarlo.

Comment: E puesto una respuesta fijate

Comment: ????????????????? no entiendo?

Comment: eso no se copia .-.

Comment: perdón error de dedo, mejor deje edito mi código para que vea como funciona,

Comment: A cabo de editar mi Código, as es como funciona mi tabla

Comment: ??????????????? EN TU CODIGO si se puede editar??????? no entiendo wft :v

Comment: Lo que trato de decir es: Que solo tenia el código de JavaScript en mi pregunta, pero me fui a editar mi pregunta y de allí le agregue el html y el css, osea ya puede ejecutar el programa que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el evento [`.dblclick()`](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) para conseguir el doble click:

```js
$('button').dblclick(function() {

    editar();
});

function editar(){

  console.log('Uhhhhhhh');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toca me dos veces seguido</button>
```

**EDIT**

Otro ejemplo:

```js
// Al hacer doble click al input se puede editar
$(document).on('dblclick', 'input', function() {

   $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});

// Añadimos las filas que quieras cuales son por defecto 'readonly'
$('button').click(function() {

    $('tr').append('<td><input size="30" type="text" value="Una fila más" readonly></td>');        
});
```

```css
td { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input size="30" type="text" value="Edita me después de dobleclick" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
<br>
<button>Insertar nueva fila</button>
```

Comment: Pero no quiero un botón, yo quiero editarlo pero cuando le de un doble click a la fila ya insertada y asi lo edite ¿Podrías darme un ejemplo basándote en mi código de Javascript? por favor...

Comment: @ReinosRic - Haz que tu fila ser clickable... te daré un ejemplo básico...

Comment: Si por favor, si me pudiera pasar el ejemplo @aldanux

Comment: @ReinosRic -  Espero que sea ahora más claro y lo puedas implementar en tu código

Comment: A cabo de usar su código que me dio de ejemplo @aldanux y no me funciono, pero de todos modos muchas gracias

Comment: @ReinosRic - algún error? Puedes crear un ejemplo ejecutable en [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: En la parte de mi codigo, le acabo de agregar el HTML y el CSS y junto con el JAVASCRIPT (El que tenia ya agregado en mi pregunta) hace que ejecute un ejemplo del como funciona mi programa.
Espero que lo pueda ver @aldanux.